# How to disable the beautify extension whenever I work in ejs file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ejs, js-beautify

I am new in Web Development.

I am using beautify extension in my visual studio code

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

when I write the html + javascript code in my ejs file, whenever I save the file, it will ruin the tab indent like the image below

[image]

I expect the javascript code in the ejs file will be like this
[image]

or at least I want to disable the beautify extension whenever I work in ejs file. how to do that ?

I have tried to add .jsbeautifyrc like the image below, but it doesn't work. when I tap save, it will ruin the indent

[image]

Comment: From the link in your OP: "You can control which file types, extensions, or specific file names should be beautified with the beautify.language setting." They have an example there, too.

Comment: Create a file named .jsbeautifyrc  in your project's root. Then copy their example code into it.

Comment: @DovRine I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work. I post the screenshot on the OP

Comment: I'm not sure why you have "ejs" in the html key. Try this: { "beautify.language": {...stuff from before}, "beautify.ignore": "\*\*/*.ejs"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm using beautify with ejs and it works fine. 
Try (shift + alt + F) to indent your code.
Don't use severals extensions that indent code, it will cause some conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **EJS Beautify** and apply some code given on their page to the **settings.json** and comment down/ remove the previous **html object** in the settings.json so that you don't find future errors in beautifying other file types like .css/ .html.